# Conditional proof/contradiction, long example problem

Tags: logic

Here are the premises/conclusion, and where I've gotten so far.

$1.$ $(W\wedge E)\rightarrow (P\vee L)$ (PR)

$2.$ $(W\wedge \neg E)\wedge R))\rightarrow (P\vee D)$ (PR)

$3.$ $((W\wedge \neg E)\wedge \neg R))\rightarrow (U\wedge \neg F)$ (PR)

$-.$ $(W\wedge F)\rightarrow (L\vee D)\vee P$ (CO)

$4.$ $\neg(U\wedge \neg F)\rightarrow \neg(W\wedge(\neg E\wedge \neg R))$ From $3$ transposition

$5.$ $(\neg U\vee \neg \neg F)\rightarrow \neg(W\wedge(\neg E\wedge \neg R))$ From $4$ DeM

$6.$ $(\neg U\vee F)\rightarrow \neg(W\wedge(\neg E\wedge \neg R))$ From $5$ Double negation

$7.$ $(\neg U\vee F) \rightarrow (\neg W\vee \neg (\neg E\wedge \neg R))$ From $6$ DeM

$8.$ $(\neg U \vee F)\rightarrow(\neg W\vee(\neg \neg E\vee \neg \neg R))$ From $7$ DeM

$9.$ $(\neg U \vee F)\rightarrow (\neg W \vee (E\vee R))$ From $8$ double negation

Here is where my conditional proof starts.

$10.$ $W\wedge F$ (Provisional assumption)

$11.$ $W$ From $10$ conjunction elimination (CE)

$12.$ $F$ From $10$ CE

$13.$ $\neg U \vee F$ From $12$ disjunctive addition (DA)

$14.$ $(\neg W\vee (E\vee R))$ From $9$, $13$ Modus Ponens

$15.$ $E\vee R$ From $14$, $11$ Disjunctive syllogism

At this point I'm lost. I've tried assuming several negations for reductio (contradiction) but I haven't gotten the desired result. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm lost too.  What rules of inference can you use?  Do you have any axioms or axiom schema at hand?

Comment: Conjunction elimination, conjunction introduction, hypothetical syllogism, disjunctive addition/syllogism, disjunctive dilemma, modus tollens/ponens. It's possible, although unlikely, that I translated the argument incorrectly. I've triple checked it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Up to step 15 it's Ok.

We can use the *Law of Excluded Middle* : $E \lor \lnot E$ and proceed by cases (*Disjunction Elimination*).

---

*(i)*

Assuming $E$, we have $W \land E$ by *Conjunction Introduction* with step 11.

Thus, from premise (1) we conclude with $(P \lor L)$ by *Modus Ponens* and then with $(P \lor (L \lor D))$ by *Disjunction Introduction* (re-arranging the terms).

*(ii)*

Assuming $\lnot E$, we have $R$ from step 15 : $E \lor R$, by *Disjunctive Syllogism*. Thus we have $((W \land \lnot E) \land R)$ and we conclude from premise (2) by *MP* with : $(P \lor D)$, and again with $(P \lor (L \lor D))$ by *Disjunction Introduction* (re-arranging the terms).

Thus, from the assumption $(W \land F)$, we have proved $(P \lor (L \lor D))$ twice, both under assumption $E$ and under assumption $\lnot E$.

I.e., we have, by *Conditional Proof* :

> $(W \land F) \vdash E \rightarrow (P \lor (L \lor D))$

and

> $(W \land F) \vdash \lnot E \rightarrow (P \lor (L \lor D))$.

With the *Law of Excluded Middle*, by [Disjunction elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination), we can conclude with :

> $(W \land F) \vdash (P \lor (L \lor D))$.

and by *Conditional Proof* with :

> > $(W \land F) \rightarrow (P \lor (L \lor D))$.

---

*Added*

If we nedd a proof of the *tautology* $E \lor \lnot E$, we can insert this "sub-proof" :

$W$ --- step 11 of the main proof

$E$ --- assumed for *CP*

$E \lor E$ --- by *Disjunction introduction*

$E$ --- by *Tautology*

$E \rightarrow E$ --- by *CP*

> $\lnot E \lor E$ --- by *Material implication*.

Answer (score 1):

The following proof using a Fitch-style [proof checker](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/) attempts the problem directly by assuming the antecedent of the goal and deriving the consequent.

[image]

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/